# Display a popover on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to copy a button pop-over effect as demonstrated [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) (Live Demo -> Launch Demo Modal).

I can see that the code for the button is the following:

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-default " title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">button</a>
```

When I include this on my page and click it, nothing happens.

Can somebody point out what I am missing?

Comment: did you call `$('a.btn').popover()`?

Comment: No, where should that go? I know very little about Javascript, can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the JS call:

```
<html>
    <!-- include bootstrap css files -->
    <body>
        <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-default " title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">button</a>
    <!-- include bootstrap js files -->
    <script>$('a.btn').popover()</script>
    </body>
</html>
```